# How to manage loading thousands of annotations on mapview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, annotations, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am developing app on iPhone.

I am using MapView for showing different app users' activity.

So there will thousands of users on my app and i need to show all them on the map with the

different annotations.

So while loading thousands annotations app may get freeze for a while.

I want to know how to load annotations according to the selected region on the map

Answer (score 2):

You can get the visible portion of the map with MKMapView's `visibleMapRect` property. Furthermore, if you're loading heaps of data, make sure you do it on a background thread. This is super easy with Grand Central Dispatch - I'd recommend watching the GCD sessions from this and last year's WWDC - they'll literally change your life.